# (NO TV) How do I copy a dead computer screen to another computer screen?

Tags: display, hdmi

So I have one computer with a broken computer screen, and another one that works fine. What I am trying to do is: Using an HDMI cable, plug both in both of the computers through the HDMI port and copy the dead computer screen to the working screen. Nothing happens when I try this.

I do not have a TV, that was broken too.

Comment: Can you not just use the working screen on the PC with the broken screen?

Comment: Yes, when I plug them in nothing happens. *They are laptops

Comment: 1) The HDMI port is just video output on each computer.  You can't accomplish anything by trying to send the output from one into the output from the other.  2) If these are laptops, there is not a trivial solution, like just plugging in a cable.  You would need to network the computers as a first step.  If you are talking about two computers concurrently using portions of a single screen, that's even more complicated.

Comment: If the laptops are on the same network, you can try to remote control the one with the dead screen from the other one. Other than that, I don't think you can do anything without another display of some sort that can take external input - which your laptop screen can't.

Comment: Then is there any way I can change my HDMI port to input audio/video instead of output?

Comment: The HDMI port cannot be used as an input port. Depending on what connectors the good laptop has, it might be possible to use some type of adapter/converter to feed the HDMI output from the bad one into appropriate input connectors on the good one, but that wouldn't just show up on the display. You would need to treat it like an input stream and use software to display it.  That's all theoretical; I've never seen anyone do it.  Networking the two laptops would be the way most people would do it.  Are the two laptops on the same network (like connected to the same router to access the Internet)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This isn't possible. Laptops don't have video inputs, just outputs.

Unless you have some kind of remote desktop software installed and configured (TeamViewer, VNC, configured RDP etc), you'll have to find a regular monitor and use it.